# Fix joint with animations in SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, fixed, skscene

I have two Sprites nodes in an SKScene. Both of them where declare as physics objects inside the SKScene editor. There are not Dynamic, they are not allow rotation, nor pinned or affected by gravity.

One of the objects is move with a method moveBy until it is close to the second object. When that happens, I create a fix joint like this:

```
 let towChopiJointFix = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(
     withBodyA: chopi.physicsBody!,
     bodyB: towTruck.physicsBody!,
     anchor: CGPoint(x: 300.0, y: 300.0 ) )
  scene!.physicsWorld.add(towChopiJointFix)
```

After the fix joint is created, I move the chopi sprite using moveBy to other position. The problem is that the second sprite (towTruck) is not moving with it. I thought that if you create a fix joint, both bodies will move together even if you move just one.

Any help?

Comment: You must add the joint to a physics world associated with the scene before it takes effect.

Comment: I think I did it in the last line. Where it says:

     scene!.physicsWorld.add(towChopiJointFix)

or is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Well, the docs show the declaration to be more like `class func joint(withBodyA bodyA: SKPhysicsBody, bodyB: SKPhysicsBody, anchor: CGPoint) -> SKPhysicsJointFixed`

Comment: Sorry I don't get what's your point. Can you show me how would you declare that with an example?

Comment: I just checked out that if I don't use the moveBy over "chopis" object but instead apply gravity over the object then the fix joint works perfect. It seems to be that this the joint don't work if you moveBy an sprite. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: My point? *maybe you're doing it wrong!* ... what type of objects are A and B? "physics objects" doesn't explain much...

Comment: It's interesting that moveBy doesn't work. Instead of using MoveBy, try apply forces to chopi to move it. That should work.